# Selenium can't find element "a"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

[The data I want to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI9gT.png)

Picture above. I want to click the "No" button and checkbox but I can't get it to work, I tried

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible((By.CssSelector("button[ng-click=\"modalCancel()\"]"))));
```

but that's all

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the button you want to click?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is looking for an element of type `button`, not `a`. Instead you need something like this:

```
a[class='button pill'][ng-click='modalCancel()']
```

In full:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(
        (By.CssSelector("a[class='button pill'][ng-click='modalCancel()']"))));
```

Comment: I would suggest that you change the `class` portion from `a[class='button pill']` to `a.button.pill`. The way you have it now it is an exact string match. If the class order changes or another class is added, your locator will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.` before `button` and your locator will work. Also, you can use `'` instead of `\"`. So change your locator to

```
By.CssSelector(".button[ng-click='modalCancel()']")
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidG was right that the element is of type `<a>` and provides us the right direction however I will like to get a bit granular and once the element is returned as you need to invoke `Click()` method so instead of using the method `ElementIsVisible()`, I would implement the method [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((By.CssSelector("a.button.pill'[ng-click=\"modalCancel()\"]")))).Click();
```